# Reduce space between icons on home screen without changing icon size

Tags: adb, screen, 7.1-nougat, home-screen, app-icons

I would like to **reduce the space between the app-icons on my home screen without changing their size**, so that I could fit more icons on one screen. The size of text or buttons in menus should not be affected.

I‘m using Android 7.1 (with LineageOS 14.1) and a solution with adb would be ok.

The „Home Screen Settings“ give me the opportunity to turn off icon labels and I can modify the “Grid size” to from “Comfortable” to “Cozy” or “Condensed”, but that does reduce the icon’s size.

I tried changing the screen resolution:

```
adb shell wm size 1080x1920
```

as well as changing the density:

```
adb shell wm density 250
```

but both changes the size of the icons.

I attached a screenshot to illustrate how much space there would actually be left on the screen for more icons.
[image: Spacing between icons could be reduced to fit more icons on the screen]
Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

Reducing the gap also reduces the sizes. If you are using the default launcher Trebuchet, you should also see `Custom` in the Grid Size settings. Clicking it allow to set the number of icons per columns and rows. Select a high number for colums and rows.

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Confirm your choice, then go back to the Home screen and rearrange the icons. You will be able to fit as many icons as you selected in the settings. The gap between them will be reduced.

[image: IMG:]

If 7x7 is not enough, you can use other launchers. Nova launcher for example allow a 12x12 grid.

**Note:** I am not related to Trebuchet nor Nova launchers developers.